# xslt duplicates on different attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to simplify an export from a database and failed both with the Muenchian Method as well as with trying to construct a recursive function.

This is my how my input looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Product>
    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="Master">word1</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="Syn1">first word 1</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="Syn2">second word 2</Value>
    </Values>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="Master">word1</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="Syn2">second word 2</Value>
    </Values>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="Master">word1</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="Syn1">third word 3</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="Syn2">second word 2</Value>
    </Values>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="Master">word2</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="Syn1">first word 1</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="Syn4">fourth word 4</Value>
    </Values>
  </Product>
</root>
```

And this is what I want to achieve:

```
<root>
  <pair>
    <master>word1</master>
    <syn>first word 1</syn>
  </pair>
  <pair>
    <master>word1</master>
    <syn>second word 2</syn>
  </pair>
  <pair>
    <master>word1</master>
    <syn>third word 3</syn>
  </pair>
  <pair>
    <master>word2</master>
    <syn>first word 1</syn>
  </pair>
  <pair>
    <master>word2</master>
    <syn>fourth word 4</syn>
  </pair>
</root>
```

Alternatively also something like this could do the trick:

```
<root>
  <pair>
    <master>word1</master>
    <syns>
      <syn>first word 1</syn>
      <syn>second word 2</syn>
      <syn>third word 3</syn>
    </syns>
  </pair>
  <pair>
    <master>word2</master>
    <syns>
      <syn>first word 1</syn>
      <syn>fourth word 4</syn>
    </syns>
  </pair>
</root>
```

Basically I get a master word and synonyms (from none up to 5 per master). I was able to generate a list with duplicates easily using templates but I failed on every attempt to either remove duplicates or just push the stuff into a variable for post-processing. The issue for me was that the synonyms can be in different attributes and always need to refer to their actual master ...

I need unique combinations of master word + any synonym - and ideally the output would be alphabetically sorted :)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible way, I think:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="syn" 
         match="Value[@AttributeID!='Master']" 
         use="concat(., '|', ../Value[@AttributeID='Master'])" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="root/Product/Values/Value[@AttributeID!='Master'][generate-id()=generate-id(key('syn', concat(., '|', ../Value[@AttributeID='Master']))[1])]">
        <pair>
            <master><xsl:value-of select="../Value[@AttributeID='Master']"/></master>
            <syn><xsl:value-of select="."/></syn>
        </pair>
    </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for sorting, you didn't say what do you want to sort by.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick. I had to add normalize-space() & lower-case() functions to the key as well as to the second generate-id in order to overcome some text issues additionally. And sorting was by master & syn but that was easy to add :)